# VS Code - Navigating between open files - CMD instead of CTRL key

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Everywhere in a MacBook I use the `CMD` key for navigation(Eg: To switch between tabs in browser or multiple if tabs are open in the Finder). How do I achieve the same in **VS code**. Currently I have to use `Ctrl` key to switch between the files open but I want to know if it's possible to change some configuration to use `CMD` instead

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the shortcuts `ctrl+1` to select first tab, `ctrl+2` to select 2nd tab and so one?

1. Open the keybindings json file (`cmd+shift+p` and type `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`).
2. Add these to the end of the file:

```
{ "key": "cmd+1", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1" },
{ "key": "cmd+2", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex2" },
{ "key": "cmd+3", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex3" },
{ "key": "cmd+4", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex4" },
{ "key": "cmd+5", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex5" },
{ "key": "cmd+6", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex6" },
{ "key": "cmd+7", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex7" },
{ "key": "cmd+8", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex8" },
{ "key": "cmd+9", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex9" }
```

If you also want to modify `ctrl+tab` and `ctrl+shift+tab` to select previous/next tab, you can add these as well (but keep in mind they might conflict with mac shortcuts):

```
{ "key": "cmd+tab",              "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup",
 "when": "!activeEditorGroupEmpty" },
{ "key": "cmd+shift+tab",        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePreviousInEditorPicker",
 "when": "inEditorsPicker && inQuickOpen" },
```